# Redirect to Privacy Policy agreement if not accepted in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I'm trying to figure out a way to redirect the user to the Privacy Policy page from each of my protected routes if the Privacy Policy is not accepted. Currently, I'm getting the true/false value from a variable that's sitting on user object in `Redux` and pass it to every protected route. Like this:

```
const isPrivacyStatementAccepted = useSelector(getIsPrivacyStatementAccepted)

  if (!isPrivacyStatementAccepted) history.push(AuthRoutes.privacyStatement)
```

Is there a more elegant/efficient way of doing the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Better way you can do where you have added routes. Something like this:

```
const isPrivacyStatementAccepted = useSelector(getIsPrivacyStatementAccepted)

<Route exact path="/">
  {isPrivacyStatementAccepted ? <Redirect to={AuthRoutes.privacyStatement} /> : <YourDashbordRoute />}
</Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are fairly close. I'm sure you've more going on with your protected route component, but this is solved with the same pattern used for [authenticated routes](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow). Check if a condition has been met and return a `Route` component with the specified props passed through, otherwise, return and render a `Redirect`.

```
const PrivacyStatementProtectedRoute = props => {
  const isPrivacyStatementAccepted = useSelector(getIsPrivacyStatementAccepted);

  return isPrivacyStatementAccepted ? (
    <Route {...props} />
  ) : (
    <Redirect to={AuthRoutes.privacyStatement} />
  );
};
```

Use like any other route

```
<Route path="/about" component={About} />
<Route path="/help" component={Help} />
<PrivacyStatementProtectedRoute path="/account" component={Account} />
```